# How to create a Pandas column to store the number of common elements between two filters of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a Pandas data frame with relevant columns A, B, C. For context, there are several C's for every combination of A, B. I would like to compute the number of elements of C that each combination (a_i, b_j) of A, B has in common with the combination (a_0, b_j), where a_0 is fixed.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_0 | b_0 | c_0 |
| a_0 | b_0 | ... |
| a_0 | b_0 | c_m |
| a_0 | b_1 | c_m+1 |
| a_0 | ... | ... |
| a_0 | b_n | c_p |
| ... | ... | ... |
| a_q | b_n | c_q |

I have tried both using for-loops and pandas.Dataframe.apply, but both were taking too long due to the size of the data frame.

Comment: Do you really mean `(a_i, b_i)` and `(a_0, b_i)`? Or `(a_i, b_j)` and `(a_0, b_j)`? Or `(a_i, b_j)` and `(a_0, b_k)`?

Comment: You're right @Corralien. Just fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but i would like into the itertools.combinations() function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: I can't think of a way to use this for my problem :( @DHJ